# How to make a count to show a dynamic block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic

In SFMC we need to show a block after the customers 4th purchase. This means when the customer have bought: 4, 8, 12 and so on.

I know I could use a dynamic content block and then you add the numbers manually, but I was wondering if it was possible to use ampscript that do the count for me. If so, how would that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use combination fo [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm), [RowCount](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/rowcount.htm) and [Mod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Mod.htm) to count the orders made by this customer, and verify if the number of orders leaves any remainder when calculated by 4:

```
%%[

VAR @customerid, @orderrows, @rowCount, @modulo

SET @customerid = AttributeValue("SubscriberKey") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
SET @orderrows = LookupRows("Orders","customerid", @customerid)
SET @rowCount = rowcount(@orderrows)

SET @modulo  = mod(@rowCount, 4)
IF (@rowCount > 0 AND @modulo == 0) THEN
ContentBlockByKey("myContentBlock")
ENDIF
]%%
```

Then use [ContentBlockByKey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbykey.htm) to fetch your content block, if the statement evaluates to true.

Comment: Would you then under @purchase add the content block id instead or how would you do that? :)

Comment: I have updated my answer, @Louise - you can use ContentBlockByKey to display your content block conditionally.