# count numbers of orders using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, count

In SFMC, I need to show a specific block at the 1st order and after that it needs to be displayed at every 4th order. Meaning 4+1 (5,9,13 and so on). My current ampscript looks like this, but I am very much in doubt on how to make the counts match.

```
%%[

VAR @customerid, @orderrows, @rowCount, @modulo

SET @customerid = _subscriberkey /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
SET @orderrows = LookupRows("Orders","subscriberkey", @customerid)
SET @rowCount = rowcount(@orderrows)

SET @modulo  = mod(@rowCount, 4)
IF rowcount(@orderrows) == 1 OR (@rowCount > 0 AND @modulo == 0) THEN
    SET @purchase = ContentBlockByID("1")
    ]%%

    %%=v(@purchase)=%%

    %%[
ENDIF
]%%
```

Thank you :)

Comment: How is this question different from your [previous one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330896/how-to-make-a-count-to-show-a-dynamic-block/330900)?

Comment: Seconded, and I honestly don't get the question. What do you mean by "making counts match"? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thank you both for asking. This is different, in a way that I need the block to be shown at the first order and after the first order it needs to at every fourth, this mean when a person have purchased one order then the block will be shown, after that it should be 1+4 so at the 5th order and then 9 and then 13. Let me know if this make more sense or need to rewrite my question. @LukasLunow

Comment: @JonasLamberty see my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you to familiarise yourself with Ampscript, by studying appropriate Trailhead modules and exploring various online resources. It's a question of adding one line and adjusting another, then you have the desired result:

```
%%[

VAR @customerid, @orderrows, @rowCount, @modulo, @one

SET @customerid = _subscriberkey /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
SET @orderrows = LookupRows("Orders","subscriberkey", @customerid)
SET @one = 1
SET @rowCount = SUBTRACT(rowcount(@orderrows),@one)

SET @modulo  = mod(@rowCount, 4)
IF rowcount(@orderrows) == 1 OR (@rowCount > 0 AND @modulo == 0) THEN
    SET @purchase = ContentBlockByID("1")
    ]%%

    %%=v(@purchase)=%%

    %%[
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: I am familiar just not with the mod function, which was new for me, but thank you for taking the time to help me out, its much appreciated.